# jquery uploadify and codeigniter session id problem

Tags: php, codeigniter, uploadify

I know this is famous question but i am not able to make it work refering to those links :-

**The problem is the same. No session id is being passed which causes a lot of problems.**

This is my config.php :-

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 2700;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

As you can see i have already set `sess_match_useragent` to false but still my session ids are getting changed. Can anybody tell me how do i pass my session ids in scriptData? Because Codeigniter doesn't use querystring approach instead it builds up pretty urls.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `$session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');` ? not quite sure what you're after

Comment: @Anthony, I'm having same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

uploadify, which is similar to SWFUpload, does not send cookie when uploading files. This is because of Adobe Flash.

You need to looking for some workaround, e.g. send sessoin id in post data with the file; or redesign the work flow of your web app.

Comment: One point missing: Unfortunately since the session id is not in the cookie but in the post data you set, you need to check it yourself instead of rely on session plug-in.